# One or more multiply defined symbols found error

Tags: c++, oop

main cpp file

```cpp
int age;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("%d", age);
    return 0;
}
```

testing cpp file

```cpp
// global variable
int age = 20;
```

I have 2 cpp files (1 is main cpp file, 2nd is testing cpp file)

So I'm trying to print out a global variable (integer) from the testing cpp file in main cpp file. It's for simple linker testing. But when I do so I get an error saying there "one or more multiply defined symbols found ".

I have tried using "char" variable and that worked fine but i dont understand why "int" doesnt work

Comment: Strong recommendation: take the [tour] that was offered when you signed up at Stackoverflow, read [ask], and read the [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section of the Help Center.

Comment: You'll need to use `extern`, but probably better if you solve this problem in a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a global variable like this, you'll need to prefix the declaration with `extern` every *except* where you define it.

```
// main.cpp
extern int age;
```

In some other file:

```
// somewhere else
extern int age;
```

In test.cpp (or where ever you want to *define* age):

```
// test.cpp (where you define it)
int age = 20;
```

Using globals like this is *not* something I would encourage however.

Comment: Example of how sharing globals across files can lead to big problems: [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order). TLDR version: Initialization order in any given cpp file (more correctly a [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))) is fixed top to bottom, but there are no guarantees of the initialization order of the cpp files themselves.